# PHP: Pulling lowest values in multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have one element of a project that is holding me back and try as I might I have not been able to get this to work. Can someone please assist me - I am sure I am just confused by it all and that there is an easy answer. I have 3 multi-dimensional arrays (3 different pricing data from different companies), EACH holding this sort of data:

```
[0] => Array
(
    [itemcode] => 27663
    [buy] => 50000
    [perquantity] => 5
)

[1] => Array
(
    [itemcode] => 38663
    [buy] => 41000
    [perquantity] => 4
)
```

The same itemcodes appear in the data from all 3 companies. I was to create an html table that has the following columns from this data:

```
ItemCode  | Supplier1  | Supplier2  | Supplier3  | Difference (2nd lowest minus lowest)
38663   | 12500  | 12425  |  16440  |  75
```

My question: Is there a shortcut to doing this, say by creating another array to temp store data? Or is there a concept you feel is required to complete this easily?

Any help is VERY appreciated.

Comment: whhy use 3 dimensional array why not use a class and create an object store all the information in the object and create array or list of objects

Comment: The data I receive is pulled from malformed JSON data that was only able to be pull apart into arrays. I don't have any control over the data extracted from the software the suppliers are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where the numbers in your HTML table come from, but I think creating a temporary array would be the way to go.

```
$items=array();
foreach ($supplier1 as $data) {
  $items[$data['itemcode']]['Supplier1buy']  = $data['buy'];
  $items[$data['itemcode']]['Supplier1perq'] = $data['perquantity'];
}
foreach ($supplier2 as $data) {
  $items[$data['itemcode']]['Supplier2buy']  = $data['buy'];
  $items[$data['itemcode']]['Supplier2perq'] = $data['perquantity'];
}
// etc.
```

To make prettier code, I think I'd need to know more about how the data works.  For example, I don't know if you really need 'perquantity'.  Is the number in your HTML table a function of buy and perquantity?

Once you've got your large `$items` array, you can walk through it to create the rows of your HTML table.

Comment: I will definitely use a temporary array - it seems the most efficient way to pull the information together. I probably only need (buy / perquanitity) to get the per each price. Another part of the problem that I need to deal with is that each price list may contain more than one list of the same itemcode. Say for bulk buying or the likes. I really only need the lowest possible price for each item from each supplier. But I think I will be right from here on out - thank you very much for your recommendations. Much appreciated /bow :)